# Sum values in a list contained in every row of a column pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a df where every row in the column `"numbers"` is a list of floats. I want to add a column to the df with the sum of those floats.

```
#current output
letter   numbers
a        [0.0, 0.1, 2.3]
b        [5, 6.7, 11.21] 

#desired output
letter   numbers           sum_result
a        [0.0, 0.1, 2.3]   2.4
b        [5, 6.7, 11.21]   22.91
```

I have tried sum(df.numbers) and get this error message

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with `sum`:

```
df['sum_result'] = df['numbers'].apply(sum)
```

Or `list comprehension`:

```
df['sum_result'] = [sum(x) for x in df['numbers']]
```